# How to Automatically Transform Specified Statements/Sentences into Capital Letters without Retyping

Tags: luatex, capitalization, convert, transformation, sentence

I have a fairly long document in which I have discovered that it may be preferable to display some statements or sentence with capital letters.

There are quite a few such statements and I would like to avoid, if possible, having to manually retype *all* of them in capital letters.

Does there a exist a command (say, analogous to `\scshape` or the like) that will accomplish this for me; or, is it possible to define such a command?

Consider the code (which is compiled with `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}
\parskip 10pt

Is there a command (or is there a way to define a command) that will automatically transform specified statements or sentences into capitalized letters?

For example, how might I transform the sentence:

\textbf{\color{red} I would like this sentence to be automatically displayed with capital letters.} 

without actually retyping the sentence as such.
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

QUESTION: Is there a way to automatically transform the sentence in red into capital letters without having to retype it?

Thank you.

Comment: LaTeX has `\MakeUppercase` but I think any decent editor can capitalize sentences.

Comment: it's not very clear how you want to specify this as you have not used structural commands in the document. You could redefine `\textbf` to uppercase but that may affect other texts, if you had used a specific `\myredquotephrase` command you could more easily redefine that, but anyway  your editor can easily uppercase the region, so there should not be any need to retype anything.

Comment: @Campa Thank you. `\Makeuppercase` does the trick.